# Custom UIBarButtonItem With BG Colour and Text Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibarbuttonitem

I have two buttons on my right of my navigation bar.

```
extension UIViewController {

func setNavigationBarItem() {

    let profileButton   = UIBarButtonItem(title: "?", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapProfileButton(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addRightBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "menu")!), profileButton]

    self.slideMenuController()?.removeRightGestures()
    self.slideMenuController()?.addRightGestures()
    }
}
```

I have created 2 buttons like this. But the profileButton I want is with background colour and having corner radius to that button. How to add it to make  it look like :

[image]

Ignore black part. `UIBarButton` will be of yellow colour background and corner radius.

Comment: What your actual expectation and what you are getting, plz specify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For that you have only one option you need to create `UIButton` instance with design that you want after that create `UIBarButtonItem` instance from that button.

```
let btnProfile = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
btnProfile.setTitle("SY", for: .normal)
btnProfile.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
btnProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
btnProfile.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Now create the `UIBarButtonItem` from that button and set it with the `rightBarButtonItems`.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addRightBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "menu")!), UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnProfile)]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    let profileButton = UIButton()
    profileButton.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:30, height:30)
    profileButton.setTitle("SY", for: .normal)
    profileButton.setTitle("SY", for: .highlighted)
    profileButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    profileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    profileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapProfileButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileButton)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

Comment: It was mistakenly updated your answer, I have already rolled back it.