# How can I make a highlighted UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, highlight, uibarbuttonitem

Just like that (sorry for the height of the image, if you know how to fix that please edit this post)

[image]

Comment: It's just a different image.

Comment: You can use the same image as a template image (`image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`), and change the `tintColor` and `backgroundColor`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425847/1176162

Comment: @Yonat but then I don't have the nice rounded corners

Comment: Try `myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5`

Comment: @Yonat bar button is not a `UIView` subclass

Comment: Use `UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)` and set the corner radius of `myButton`.